# Convert to varchar max inside string_agg function

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a function a STRING_AGG function which is throwing error

> Error message: STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of
> 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

As this [Documentation](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9371/sql-string-agg-function/#:%7E:text=Error%20message%3A%20STRING_AGG%20aggregation%20result,varchar(max)%20as%20follows.), says I need to convert to `varchar(max)`

Current:

```
 STRING_AGG(CONCAT([CT].[DeviceType] , ': ' , [COM].[Address]) , ', ')) AS [Contact]
```

Try:

```
STRING_AGG(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),(CONCAT([CT].[DeviceType] , ': ' , [COM].[Address])) , ', ')) AS [Contact]
```

But it is throwing error:

> The STRING_AGG function requires 2 argument(s).

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have put the separator within the *concat*, it should be the second parameter:

```
STRING_AGG(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),(CONCAT([CT].[DeviceType] , ': ' , [COM].[Address])) ), ', ') AS [Contact]
```