# Select all tables in a database using T-SQL and a WHILE loop?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I am attempting to return all table results from each table in my database *AdventureWorksDW2019*. Would my current approach work somehow? Or is there more simple/efficient way to do this? In my current approach, I am storing all of the table names in a temp table with their respective row number when sorted by ascending name. Then, I am trying to wrap that in a WHILE statement to loop through each table and select all results from each table. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  #TableNamesSorted

SELECT
    name,
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name)
    INTO #TableNamesSorted
    FROM
        SYSOBJECTS
    WHERE
        xtype = 'U'

DECLARE @i INT = 0;
DECLARE @currentTableName varchar(25);

WHILE @i < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TableNamesSorted)
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    SET @currentTableName = (SELECT name from #TableNamesSorted WHERE RowNum = @i)
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT @currentTableName)
END
```

Comment: Would it work? Why not try it and see? That would be much quicker than asking us, and more reliable.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. I am getting the error, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'."

Comment: the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'`  is due to you did not assign an alias to the derived table `SELECT * FROM (SELECT @currentTableName)`

Comment: @Squirrel That's just the start of the problems. You cannot use a variable as a table name in this manner. This will require dynamic sql.

Comment: @SMor, thank you, this should steer me in the right direction.

Comment: I know. I am waiting for OP to post the ultimate error :)

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Better idea: `sp_executesql` with a string from `SELECT STRING_AGG(  CONCAT( 'SELECT * FROM ', TABLE_NAME, ';' ), CONCAT( CHAR(13), CHAR(10) ) ) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Comment: @Dai I am mostly trying to familiarize myself with the database's design; skimming through each table

Comment: @Dai that is a great idea but STRING_AGG maxes out at 8000 characters which if there is a lot of tables and/or the names are long that would bomb out fairly quickly.

Comment: @SeanLange The 8000-char limit doesn't apply if you use it with an explicit `CONVERT( varchar(max), )`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71355661/convert-to-varchar-max-inside-string-agg-function

Comment: @Dai - cool didn't know you could do that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I absolutely abhor loops when they are not needed and this is one of those times. You can easily generate a string with a select top 10 from each table. Please notice this will also handle schemas which if you have more than one schema your solution would fail. I also included the name of the table as the first column so you know what table you are looking at sample data for. It is this simple, no temp tables, no loops.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

select @sql += 'select top 10 TableName = ''' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ''', * from  ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';'
from sys.tables t
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are likely better means to go about this (thank you Dai and SMor),

I got it to work using this:

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.#TableNamesSorted') IS NULL DROP TABLE #TableNamesSorted

SELECT
    name,
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name)
    INTO #TableNamesSorted
    FROM
        SYSOBJECTS
    WHERE
        xtype = 'U'

DECLARE @i INT = 0;
DECLARE @currentTableName varchar(25);


DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @TableCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TableNamesSorted)
WHILE @i <=  @TableCount
BEGIN TRY

    SET @i = @i + 1
    SET @currentTableName = (SELECT name from #TableNamesSorted WHERE RowNum = @i)
    
    SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ', @currentTableName)
    EXEC (@SQL)

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH  
Print 'Errors on ' + @currentTableName 
END CATCH;
```

Comment: One can easily argue that selecting all rows from all tables is not a useful method "to familiarize myself with the database's design". Normally one looks at the DDL and the relationships between tables. Until you understand what the tables actually represent as entities in a model, looking vast amounts of data seems a bit strange.

Comment: @SMor On the contrary: too-often databases are underdocumented - and even if the foreign-key relationships make-sense seeing the definition of a column won't really tell you exactly what it contains, e.g. if you have a column named `Name` you _need_ to see a sample of the data in the table to see if it's a first-name, last-name, all-upper-case, etc. Seeing sample data is as important as the DDL, imo.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.